# Don't forget to rename your test classes when copying test file setup lines. Here's why

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

How can setup in one Ruby Minitest file cause six errors in a different Minitest file?

I don't even know how I'd look this one up. Hope you can help.

I was writing unit tests (in Minitest for Ruby, for [this "to do list" learning project](https://github.com/SangerGroup/todo)), and my tests were passing fine. Then, I started writing tests for a method in a new file, [test_todo_helpers.rb](https://github.com/SangerGroup/todo/blob/master/test/test_todo_helpers.rb), and the first time I ran the file's setup method, I got six errors. And it turns out that the errors were errors in a completely different test script, [test_task.rb](https://github.com/SangerGroup/todo/blob/master/test/test_task.rb). When I simply remove the first test file, all my tests pass! Note, I didn't touch the source files at all.

Here's a sample error message, one of the six errors (all of them were "undefined method for nil").

```
  1) Error:
TestTask#test_check_description:
NoMethodError: undefined method `check_description' for nil:NilClass
    C:/Users/user/Dropbox/_Programming/Ruby/learning_projects/todo/test/test_task.rb:41:in `test_check_description'
```

In [test_todo_helpers.rb](https://github.com/SangerGroup/todo/blob/master/test/test_todo_helpers.rb), I was able to narrow down the issue to a single line, and here it is: `@store = TaskStore.new('tasks.yml')`. Comment out that line, in one test file, and all the errors in another test file magically go away!

I am totally like WTF? Why should my loading my yaml store into an instance variable in one test file cause an object in a different test file, which normally is not `nil`, to suddenly be `nil`?

I was thinking that maybe I need to do some `teardown`? I never do that because I never learned why it's necessary. Can tests in one file affect tests in another file? (I'm a beginner.)

This struck me as a potential learning opportunity so here I am. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Perhaps you cannot create two stores with the same name? I would try to delete the store and its yaml file before starting the next test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test_task.rb` and `test_todo_helpers.rb` both provide a definition of `TestTask`. This means the two files tests are being treated as a single set of tests by minitest. If you change `class TestTask < Minitest::Test` to `class TestTodoHelpers < Minitest::Test` in `test_todo_helpers.rb`, all of your tests pass.

Comment: Ugh. You're totally right. I copied the first few lines of the test file from `test_task.rb` and when I renamed the test class as you say, the tests all passed. Thanks! Happy New Year!